# Purpose of order by group by sql statements

Tags: sql

Can someone please tell me the difference between **group by** and **order by** using sql. I understand **group by** use a having clause and together with aggregate functions like **sum**, **avg** etc. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;
```

The `ORDER BY` keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more columns.

The `ORDER BY` keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword.

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name,column_name ASC|DESC;
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)